# C enumeration not recognized in c++

Tags: c++, c

I'm having some trouble with using an enumeration defined in a c header in the main function of a c++ program.  The code is similar to this:

main.cpp:

```
extern "C"
{
#include my_c_header.h
}
//...
int main(void)
{
  my_c_function(channel_1);
  return 0;
}
```

my_c_header.h:

```
typedef enum channel
{
  channel_0,
  channel_1
};

void my_c_function(channel ch)
{
  //...
}
```

The compiler is complaining that it cannot resolve symbol 'channel_1'.  The compiler is tms470, but I don't know if the problem is peculiar to this compiler or if there is something amiss in this mixing of c and c++

Comment: in your code you include a .h, but you list the file as a .c ...

Comment: You are right, so I fixed it.

Comment: `typedef enum channel { ... };` That is surprisingly valid code, but most probably (because of the later use: `void my_c_function( channel ch )` you are missing the `channel` after the braces

Comment: Also, does your `my_c_header.h` file have the full definition of `my_c_function()` in int without the function being `inline` or `static`?  That could work but is likely to cause problems, and it's another indication that the code you've posted is different enough from the actual code that I'm not sure we can help you with your problem. There's a good chance that the problem you're running into is caused by something not shown in what you've posted.

Answer (score 6):

That's not a valid `typedef` statement, you're missing the aliased name.

Try

```
typedef enum
{
  channel_0,
  channel_1
} channel;
```

(It could actually be legal, but it wouldn't introduce the name `channel` into the search space used by the C compiler.)

Comment: +1 I was wondering about that, but wasn't sure. Congrats on your 80k mark too!

Comment: I thought about that, and tried with the name before, after and before and after the symbols. This link: http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1832/21.htm seems to indicate that the "preferred" syntax is to put the name before the list.  Errors are the same with all 3 syntaxes, The syntax with the alias before the list only generates a warning indicating that , it also generates a warning that a typtedef name is required.  Apparently it prefers it at the end, but that does not fix the problem of the enumerations being unrecognized.

Comment: But surely the problem is that it can't resolve `channel_1` not `channel`? If that was the case wouldn't it complain about the definition of `void my_c_function(channel ch)` ?

Comment: That said, I got `warning: ‘typedef’ was ignored in this declaration` until I changed the typedef / enum construct as you said, after which it compiled fine - I stand corrected!

Comment: Failure to resolve `channel_0` and 'channel_1' is indeed the problem.  The typedef syntax may or may not be a red herring to the issue at large, but I have little faith in that being at the heart of the problem, as I've tried every variation I know of, without any change to the core of the problem.

Comment: Surprisingly it is valid. Not what was intended by the user, but is is valid in C++. The typedef-ed name is optional in a typedef definition, so `typedef struct X {};` is a valid definition of `X` as a type.

Comment: @2NinerRomeo: Notice that the "preferred version" doesn't include the word `typedef`, and doesn't make the bare name available in C.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you defined the enum inside the source instead of the header file.